# Add custom dictionary for spell check to Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I wonder if it is posible to add a custom dictionary for my language to Android Studio.

Thanks

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You can download an ASCII dictionary for your language from http://www.winedt.org/dictASCII.html and then add it to Android Studio:

1. Go to Settings -> Spelling -> Dictionaries
2. Click +
3. Select path to your dictionaries folder (inside you must have plaintext word lists with .dic extension)
4. Restart Android Studio

Comment: Dictionnary files from www.winedt.org must be encoded in UTF-8 so non ASCII characters are correctly interpreted by android studio.

Comment: This worked for me http://www.winedt.org/dict.html